# installed unstable graphic driver and it crashed, how to restore normal graphics driver?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, apt

it is a 64 bit ubuntu 12.04 2 LTS, with NVIDIA graphic card.

I tried installing driver from:

http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html

as the system is connected to network and lot of the system are mounted in local system. Installation is struck at "Searching for conflicting X files" as it is trying to scan a very big network.

Is there a way to install it using apt-get or avoid "Searching for conflicting X files" step?

I'm not sure what more details are required, please comment if you need more details to fix this,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```